# ModBus on TCP with Java

Tags: java, modbus-tcp

[image]I have a HLK-DIO16 device supporting modbus over tcp.

In the user manual I see an example to read Simultaneously 16 digital input

the string is:

0x01030026000165c1

01 device address
 03 function code
 0026 register initial address
 0001 register number
 65c1 crc

Using java code with jlibmodus library
the method would be

```
int[] registerValues = m.readHoldingRegisters(slaveId, offset, quantity);
```

which parameters value for the 3 variables to reproduce the string
 0x01030026000165c1

?

Comment: which version of jlibmodbus is that?

Comment: in this other manual

drive.google.com/file/d/…

they said that modbus is only over RS interface.. for TCP HEX instruction protocol..

the "hilink" assistance drive me crazy.. I asked them a way to control the device remotely by wifi and they send me modbus specification..

So I need the hex protocol specification? do you think I will sent hex by tcp socket?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** the answer below applies only to Modbus RTU over serial for the particular device of the question, which does not seem to support Modbus TCP (it does have support for a different HEX protocol over TCP port 8080 though).

This is how to translate these different naming conventions:

`slaveId` = Device Address (`01` in your case)

`offset`  = Initial Register (from where you start reading), `0x0026` in your example above, which is 38 decimal.

`quantity`= Number of registers to read (that should be `0001` if you want to read 1 register, which will include 16 DIs as bits)

The function code `0x03` and CRC will be added by the library when you call `readHoldingRegisters` so you don't have to worry about them.

So you can do:

```
int[] registerValues = m.readHoldingRegisters(1, 38, 1);
```

And you should get those 16 bits in your `registerValues` variable. For instance, if you get:

`registerValues=255`

It would mean all your inputs are set high (to 1).

Comment: thank you Marcos.
I tried it but I got "ModbusIOException: 6 bytes expected, but 0 received."

the connection was fine (isConnected() return true)

Comment: Strange... I could not get a hold on a manual for your device. If you have a copy to share I can take a look. Sometimes the isConnected only means you have correctly created the client instance. Can you ping the device and make sure port 502 is open?

Comment: the port configured is 8080 (using the default 502 the connection give a socket exception because wrong port)

the manual is 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DrobylPN8ieLZpM8GIsed_zolV7RxX6M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see the mistake now, the address should be an HEX number not an INT as I wrote. Can you try changing 26 to 38 (0x26=38 decimal)? The slaveID and quantity should be in HEX too, but those would be the same...

Comment: it can't works also converting in hex.
I tried a for loop over offset trying values from 1 to 100.. but nothing
It's very strange..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196713/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-marcos-g).